# redirect_to @article doesn't work. article_url not defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As I said above. I use my code like this.

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end
  def new
  end
  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    @article.save
    redirect_to @article
  end

  private
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
    end
end
```

But it always doesn't work. I have no idea and other questions are no use.
This is my template.

```
<%= form_for :article,url: articles_path do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You are using the wrong path:  `articles_path` is for the index action, `article_path` is for the show action - and you don't have an index action.  Do `rake routes` and see what that tells you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault I mistyped resources in the the route.

```
resources :articles
```